# deterministic sampling for multivariate discrete distributions

Tags: probability, sampling, multivariate-analysis, discrete-data, approximation

Unscented transform can approximate expectations well via deterministic sampling.
if $f(x) = N(\mu,\Sigma)$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$ then 
$\int f(x) h(x) \approx \frac{1}{2d}\sum_{i=1}^{2d} h(x_k)$ where $x_k$ are the so called sigma points that are chosen as
$ x_k = \mu \pm (\sqrt{d\Sigma})_k$ where $(\sqrt{\Sigma})_k$ is the kth column of the square root.

So here is my question. Is there a similar deterministic sampling equivalent for discrete distributions? That is, can I approximate the expectation of a function over a discrete distribution via deterministic sampling as in unscented transform.
$ \sum h(x)f(x) \approx \frac{1}{n} \sum h(x_k)$ where $x_k \sim f(x)$ and x is say over a discrete space. For the simplest case assume that x is defined on $\left\{0,1\right\}^d$.

The main reason I want to do is approximately is the huge combinatorial space. I don't want to sum over $2^d$ possible combinations just to compute a mean. So practically my question can be restated as, is there a efficient way to compute the mean of a multivariate discrete distribution?

I know that I can do standard Monte Carlo averaging but that is not as efficient as deterministic sampling based approaches like the unscented transform.

More clarification: For the Gaussian case, I know the mean and variance of the input distribution and I pick the sigma-points accordingly. With this approach expectation of functions up to cubic terms are exact. So my question is similar, assume I know something about my special multivariate distribution (it does not need to be a super-general discrete distribution, i.e. bernoulli? ). Which points should I sample to approximate the expectation nicely?

Comment: have you considered Quasi-Monte Carlo (QMC) methods? Despite the name QMC methods are deterministic in the sense that the samples are (usually a grid-like covering of a $d$ dimensional space.