# expectation of multivariate discrete distribution

Tags: probability, sampling, multivariate-analysis, discrete-data, approximation

The expectation of a function $f(x)$ over a probability distribution $p(x)$ where $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and $x_i \in \left\{1,\dots,K\right\}$ requires a summation over all possible $K^n$ combinations.

$ E[f(x)] = \sum_x f(x)p(x)$

For large scale systems this exponential grow up is formidable. I am wondering whether it is possible to approximate this expectation somehow.

For a simpler case, which I am mainly interested in; consider a fully factorized distribution
$p(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n p(x_i)$. For this case is there any efficient way of calculating the expectation?

$ E[f(x)] = \sum_x f(x) \prod_{i=1}^n p(x_i)$

If $f(x)$ was also $\prod f_i(x_i)$ than things would be simple due to $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$ however for general nonlinear $f(\cdot)$ things get coupled.

For the simplest case which is still of interest to me consider multivariate Bernoulli variables. Again assume $p(x) = \prod p(x_i)$ and $p(x_i=1)=\alpha_i$. Is there a cheap way of calculating 
$ E[f(x)] = \sum_{x \in \left\{0,1\right\}^n} f(x) \prod_{i=1}^n p(x_i)$

As I mentioned, the result does not need to be exact, a fast approximation scheme is what I am looking for. The first approximation idea that comes to my mind is Monte-Carlo approximation; however I don't think that it will be efficient and accurate enough.

Comment: As you say in your question, one simple (and pretty general) way to approximate expectations is via Monte Carlo methods. It is not harmed by high dimensionality. When you say "I don't think it will be efficient and accurate enough." can you be more explicit about what you think the specific problem is? Accuracy can always be improved by more sampling and there are a variety of methods for improving efficiency (information per draw from the distribution).

Comment: @Glen_b I asked a similar question here: [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/100566/deterministic-sampling-for-multivariate-discrete-distributions) I agree MC scales wrt dimension but I need to calculate such expectations a lot and to get accurate enough approximations I will need particles that scales with dimension. I am looking for something that is like unscented transform, i.e. deterministic sampling.

Comment: @Glen_b More or less I am looking something that can approximate accurately using few samples like Unscented transform. UT for instance requires $2d+1$ samples for $d$ dimensional Gaussian distributions with know  mean and covariance. The problem is analogous to the Gaussian case where UT do wonders so I wonder if there is any equivalent for the discrete case.